# ¿Hay un equivalente femenino para "braguetazo"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, locuciones

Un [braguetazo](https://dle.rae.es/braguetazo) es

> Casarse por interés con una mujer rica.

¿Hay una palabra equivalente para el caso inverso, para "Casarse por interés con un hombre rico"?

Answer (score 1):

No he encontrado una versión exclusiva para la mujer, pero tienes un término que se puede aplicar a ambos sexos por igual:

> **[cazafortunas](https://dle.rae.es/cazafortunas)**
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que trata de casarse con alguien acaudalado.

Un término parecido que aplica solo a hombres es el siguiente:

> **[cazadotes](https://dle.rae.es/cazadotes)**
>
> 1. m. Hombre que trata de casarse con una mujer rica.

En todo caso, estas palabras describen a la persona que trata de casarse con alguien rico, pero no a la acción de casarse en sí, como lo hace *braguetazo*. No encuentro ninguna contrapartida femenina para tan sonoro vocablo. Uno podría pensar en *bragazo*, que al menos hace alusión a la *braga*, pero el problema es que esa palabra sería muy similar a esta otra, ya existente y con un significado distinto:

> **[bragazas](https://dle.rae.es/bragazas)**
>
> Del aum. de *bragas*, pl. de *braga<sup>1</sup>*.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Hombre que se deja dominar o persuadir con facilidad, especialmente por su mujer. U. t. c. adj.

Answer (score 0):

Notablemente en castellano no parece haber un término equivalente (un sustantivo con el subfijo "azo", aumentativo, como `Gol-*azo*) para referir al casamiento de una mujer con un hombre de fortuna.

Me refiero a la inexistencia de una palabra con el mísmo sentido, pero opuesta en género (como lo sería acaso `bragazo`, en tanto [braga](https://dle.rae.es/braga?m=form) es la prenda femenina contrapuesta a [bragueta](https://dle.rae.es/bragueta?m=form), que originó 'braguetazo')

Como dato curioso puede notarse que la lengua si alude de manera indeterminada (en cuanto al género sexual) a quien intenta una unión económicamente favorecedora

> [cazafortunas](https://dle.rae.es/cazafortunas?m=form)

> 1. m. y f. Persona que trata de casarse con alguien acaudalado.